# android Edittext change color background of text when input

Tags: android, android-edittext

i have edit text like this :

```
<EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="input something"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#04ff00"
            android:textColorHint="#0094fd"/>
```

this is result:

[image]

like image, I want to change background of text when input in edittext.
how to do it?

Comment: Just to be sure, you want to change the background color of selected text, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve that behaviour add `textColorHighlight` to your `EditText`:

```
<EditText
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:hint="input something"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:textSize="20sp"
      android:textColor="#04ff00"
      android:textColorHint="#0094fd"
      android:textColorHighlight="@android:color/holo_red_light"/>
```

The final result is something like this:
[image]

Comment: I was try, in genymotion, it alright. but when test on real device use android 5.0.2, it not like that.

Comment: Hmmm, I checked on my Nexus 5x with Android M and it looks ok... can you give more details or maybe try a clean build?

Comment: oh, just my fault. sorry about that. thank you so much